# How do I stop a pip install if there are package dependency conflicts?

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, python-venv

I did `pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.12.3` because my GPU can only support CUDA 9, while the latest `tensorflow-gpu==1.14.0` requires a minimum of CUDA 10. One of the package dependencies is `tensorboard`.

I want to do `pip install tensorflow`. However, the latest version warns that a newer version of `tensorboard` must be installed, then automatically proceeded to uninstall the existing version and install the newer one. Is there a way to have pip halt or at least ask for confirmation instead of proceeding on its own in such a situation? I'm trying to figure out which is a compatible version of `tensorflow` that doesn't require newer versions of package dependencies shared with `tensorflow-gpu`.

**Edit**

ok just to clarify, this isn't a tensorflow-specific question, I'm just using it as an example because I just happen to be doing that right now.

To generalise: I installed an older version of package A, which has a dependency on an older version of package B. I want to install package C, which also has a dependency on package B. However, the latest version of C requires the latest version of B. When I try to install C, it automatically uninstalled the older B and installed the newest version. How do I stop it from doing that?

Right now my only workaround is to install a version of C, wait for it to automatically uninstall something, then interrupt the installation of C, and reinstall the version of the dependency package that was uninstalled. Then I step down to the next older version C, and repeat. Basically, a trial and error process.

Is there a more proper and elegant solution? I'm fine with it giving a warning that C requires a newer version of B and then terminating at that point, or prompting for a confirmation before proceeding to uninstall, instead of doing it automatically without asking.

I'm using PyCharm's venv, so alternatively I'm also fine if there's a way to revert the latest change to the environment i.e. uninstall C and whatever new dependency packages that's installed, reverting to the list of installed packages before I executed `pip install C`.

Hopefully that doesn't sound too convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done any work with `tensorflow` so I can't help you with that part, but I can suggest you using virtual environments when testing out stuff and not risking breaking system `Python` or upgrading packages you want at specific version.

`python -m venv env` to create virtual environment called `env`. `source env/bin/activate` to make the virtual environment active and `deactivate` to *leave* it.

Regarding the overwriting old packages, I haven't found options for promting installing new version nor an option to ignore requirements for a certain package. This is probably because developers can specify which version of dependencies are required and thus if `pip` finds outdated package, the package you wish to instal would probably not be usable with it.

However, you might try installing the newest version of `tensorflow` and let it install requirements it needs and then simply uninstall them using `pip uninstall PACKAGE-NAME` and install the version you wish with `pip install PACKAGE-NAME==x.x.x`.

Also, [here is a guide that explains installation of `tensorflow` with CUDA 9](https://www.pytorials.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-gpu-with-cuda-9-2-for-python-on-ubuntu/). It seems that they are using version 1.8 for CUDA 9.2 and 1.7 for CUDA 9.1.

Comment: Well this isn't a tensorflow-specific question to be fair, I'm just using it as an example because that's what I happen to be trying to do right now. And as it happens I am actually doing this in my PyCharm venv so got that virtual env covered.

Comment: I see. I suggest you trying the steps I described in last two paragraphs and tell us how did it go

Comment: Is there any way to check the list of dependencies+versions for a given package via pip or something? Preferably before installation but if the only possible ways must have the package already installed I guess I can live with that. If there's such a way I think it'll go a long way to helping me manage my problem.

Comment: It should be written somewhere in source code. You should look for file `requirements.txt`, there are package names and versions written inside (there might be something else as well) or inside `setup.py` file (however, it is likely that `find_packages` function is used to find requirements). Note: it is possible that `requirements.txt` is not present in source

Comment: I have just found that you can do `pip install --no-deps`. I think this might solve your problem